# NextJS and Storybook

Tags: javascript, next.js, storybook

Does NextJS support NPM Modules in Storybook? I'm trying to add some components to my NextJS scripts, but getting errors on Storybook.

To replicate, create a blank NextJS project, add an NPM module, add Storybook, and try to run it.

ie;

```
yarn create next-app --typescript
cd my-app
npx sb init
yarn add swiper --save
```

Open `./stories/Button.tsx`
Add the following import statements at the top of the file:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import 'swiper/css';
```

Then run `yarn storybook`. I get the error:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ start-storybook -p 6006
info @storybook/react v6.3.7
info 
info => Loading presets
info => Loading 1 config file in "C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\.storybook"
info => Loading 9 other files in "C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\.storybook"
info => Adding stories defined in "C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\.storybook\main.js"
info => Using prebuilt manager
info => Using implicit CSS loaders
info => Using default Webpack4 setup
(node:12912) DeprecationWarning: Default PostCSS plugins are deprecated. When switching to '@storybook/addon-postcss',
you will need to add your own plugins, such as 'postcss-flexbugs-fixes' and 'autoprefixer'.

See https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated-default-postcss-plugins for details.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
webpack built preview 669852bfe6f0fb0549dc in 6158ms
× ｢wdm｣: Hash: 669852bfe6f0fb0549dc
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 6158ms
Built at: 02/09/2021 12:53:36
                                        Asset      Size        Chunks                          Chunk Names
                           0.iframe.bundle.js   206 KiB             0  [emitted]
                       0.iframe.bundle.js.map   144 KiB             0  [emitted] [dev]
                           1.iframe.bundle.js   222 KiB             1  [emitted]
                       1.iframe.bundle.js.map   212 KiB             1  [emitted] [dev]
                           2.iframe.bundle.js    91 KiB             2  [emitted]
                       2.iframe.bundle.js.map  83.5 KiB             2  [emitted] [dev]
                           3.iframe.bundle.js   372 KiB             3  [emitted]        [big]
                       3.iframe.bundle.js.map   412 KiB             3  [emitted] [dev]
                           4.iframe.bundle.js  15.7 KiB             4  [emitted]
                       4.iframe.bundle.js.map  16.6 KiB             4  [emitted] [dev]
                                  iframe.html  4.45 KiB                [emitted]
                        main.iframe.bundle.js  89.8 KiB          main  [emitted]               main
                    main.iframe.bundle.js.map  40.1 KiB          main  [emitted] [dev]         main
                runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js  36.3 KiB  runtime~main  [emitted]               runtime~main
            runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js.map  37.6 KiB  runtime~main  [emitted] [dev]         runtime~main
static/media/stories/assets/code-brackets.svg  1.42 KiB                [emitted]
       static/media/stories/assets/colors.svg  8.31 KiB                [emitted]
     static/media/stories/assets/comments.svg  1.49 KiB                [emitted]
    static/media/stories/assets/direction.svg  1.25 KiB                [emitted]
         static/media/stories/assets/flow.svg  1.36 KiB                [emitted]
       static/media/stories/assets/plugin.svg  2.12 KiB                [emitted]
         static/media/stories/assets/repo.svg   1.6 KiB                [emitted]
     static/media/stories/assets/stackalt.svg  2.49 KiB                [emitted]
                vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js  4.98 MiB  vendors~main  [emitted]        [big]  vendors~main
            vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js.map  4.48 MiB  vendors~main  [emitted] [dev]         vendors~main
Entrypoint main [big] = runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js.map vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js.map main.iframe.bundle.js main.iframe.bundle.js.map
[0] multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/preview.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/storybook-addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined 196 bytes {main} [built]
[./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js] 434 bytes {main} [built]
[./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js] 3.83 KiB {main} [built]
[./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js] 26 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.79 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.79 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.8 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.8 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.79 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.79 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.79 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/preview.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.79 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js] 105 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js] 97 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/storybook-addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.79 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
    + 1221 hidden modules

ERROR in ./stories/Button.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'swiper/css' in 'C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\stories'
 @ ./stories/Button.tsx 15:0-20
 @ ./stories/Header.tsx
 @ ./stories/Header.stories.tsx
 @ ./stories sync ^\.(?:(?:^|[\\/]|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$
 @ ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/preview.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/storybook-addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined

ERROR in ./stories/Button.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'swiper/react' in 'C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\stories'
 @ ./stories/Button.tsx 14:0-51 34:34-40 36:35-46 38:28-39 40:28-39
 @ ./stories/Header.tsx
 @ ./stories/Header.stories.tsx
 @ ./stories sync ^\.(?:(?:^|[\\/]|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$
 @ ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/preview.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/storybook-addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined
Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
                          Asset      Size               Chunks  Chunk Names
    __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  6.23 KiB  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/templates/index.ejs] 1.98 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'swiper/css' in 'C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\stories'
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:925:10
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:6877:13
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:213:14
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
resolve 'swiper/css' in 'C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\stories'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\package.json (relative path: ./stories)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\stories\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\Personal\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules
        using description file: C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\package.json (relative path: ./css)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\css doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\css.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\css.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\css.jsx doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\css.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\css.tsx doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\css.json doesn't exist
            .cjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\css.cjs doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\css doesn't exist
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'swiper/react' in 'C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\stories'
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:925:10
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:6877:13
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:213:14
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
resolve 'swiper/react' in 'C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\stories'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\package.json (relative path: ./stories)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\stories\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\Personal\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules
        using description file: C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\package.json (relative path: ./react)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react is not a file
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react.jsx doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react.tsx doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react.json doesn't exist
            .cjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react.cjs doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                using path: C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react\index
                  using description file: C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\package.json (relative path: ./react/index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react\index doesn't exist
                    .mjs
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react\index.mjs doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react\index.js doesn't exist
                    .jsx
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react\index.jsx doesn't exist
                    .ts
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react\index.ts doesn't exist
                    .tsx
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react\index.tsx doesn't exist
                    .json
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react\index.json doesn't exist
                    .cjs
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\Projects\Personal\test2\my-app\node_modules\swiper\react\index.cjs doesn't exist

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've followed numerous tutorials on adding Storybook to NextJS, and they all seem to error in a similar way:

- https://nebulab.com/blog/nextjs-tailwind-storybook
- https://dev.to/wonder2210/next-js-storybook-typescript-2021-guide-2ab4
- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/next-js-storybook-3f8e5a8dab3d

Has something changed or broken? Any ideas would be most welcome.

Open to suggestions.

Comment: Assuming everything is configured correctly and you're on next 11 you need to use the webpack 5 version of storybook (6.3+) and manually add webpack@5 as a dependency in your package.json

Comment: @SeanW I ran `yarn add webpack@5 --save` but still get the same error. I'm running Storybook 6.3.6 and Next 11.0.1

Comment: Does storybook work without your custom code using the default components.

Comment: @SeanW If I remove the two lines from Buttons.tsx then everything works perfectly. It seems to be importing any NPM module (anything that is in node_modules) causes an error. Doesn't seem to matter what the NPM module is.

Comment: @ScottFreeman I must say that the general approach we follow is that write all the code and css in our component and in storybook stories we just import that component. Ik it's little silly comment.